# How to get HttpServletRequest from spring proxy object

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

Into an interceptor class I want to get the HttpServletRequest object:

```
public class MyEndpointInterceptorAdapter extends EndpointInterceptorAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

 ...

}
```

What I actually get is a proxy object of HttpServletRequest.
[image]

How I can get the original HttpServletRequest object out of this proxy spring object?

Update1:

Per request here is the stack trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy622 cannot be cast to weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getOriginalRequest(ServletRequestImpl.java:1654)
at weblogic.servlet.security.ServletAuthentication.runAs(ServletAuthentication.java:726)
at weblogic.servlet.security.ServletAuthentication.runAs(ServletAuthentication.java:710)
at weblogic.servlet.security.ServletAuthentication.runAs(ServletAuthentication.java:681)
at eu.cec.digit.ecas.client.authentication.AbstractWeblogic9ServletAuthentication.impersonate(AbstractWeblogic9ServletAuthentication.java:170)
at eu.europa.ec.comp.cmr.iop.soap.security.interceptor.EcasTicketAuthenticationInterceptor.authenticateAndImpersonate(EcasTicketAuthenticationInterceptor.java:107)
at eu.europa.ec.comp.cmr.iop.soap.security.interceptor.EcasTicketAuthenticationInterceptor.handleRequest(EcasTicketAuthenticationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:227)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:884)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at eu.europa.ec.comp.cmr.iop.soap.security.filter.ExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilterInternal(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:23)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)

Comment: Why do you need it? Can you explain what the proxy does?

Comment: I know what the proxy object does, but I need the original object to pass it to a library that I use, and that library does not want the proxy object

Comment: What, _exactly_, is the failure case when you pass the proxy?

Comment: Exactly the classic cast exception: can not convert: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy622 cannot be cast to weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl

Comment: Something much more fundamental is broken if something is attempting to cast the request to a specific implementation class. Please provide more details, _particularly_ including the stack trace.

Comment: The library that I use i can not change it to not use it. If there are made some mistakes i can not change them, i need to leave with them...

Comment: You can use `AopTestUtils.getTargetObject`, but note that this is _very_ likely to cause hard-to-trace glitches if advice is being applied and then bypassed.

Comment: well, i am in real code, so no test libraries allowed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fund the answer, from the proxy object returned by spring on @Autowired, you dont have access to original HttpServletRequest object.

you can get the HttpServletRequest object, through a different path from: RequestContextHolder

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = 
 ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

This gives you the original HttpServletRequest.